# IOS Tracking Facebook installation, app install number not growing

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As per this [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/creating-ads), In my app I have implemented the last `Facebook` SDK and I have added the following method in my `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];

 }
```

All seems to work correctly in the begining. I have installed my app by `Xcode` and in the Analytics section of my Facebook app I could see (under events section) :

```
App Installs: 1
```

To check this behavior I installed my app in another `iPhone` but the App Installs number is still  1.

What causes this behavior? Installing the app in another device apparently is not creating a new installation event?

Comment: Did you use the same Facebook user account on both devices? In that case, it can be that it's recorded as one install.